# How to delete part of a filename for multiple files using R

Tags: r, rename

I'm using R studio 3.4.4 on Windows

I have file names that are like this:

```
1-2.edit-sites.annot.xlsx
2-1.edit-sites.annot.xlsx
...
10-1.edit-sites.annot.xlsx
```

I'm using the following code to rename the files (in order, including 1,2,3...10,11, etc)

```
file.rename(mixedsort(sort(list.files(pattern="*edit-sites.annot.xlsx"))), paste0("Sample ", 1:30))
```

But I can never remove the edit-sites.annot part. It seems like the `.` before edit is making R mess up with the extension of the file! When I use the code above, I get `Sample 1.edit-sites.annot.xlsx` but I would like `Sample 1.xlsx`

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work. For each file that is named "[num1]-[num2].edit-sites.annot.xlsx" it will rename it to "Sample [num1]-[num2].xlsx":

```
fnames <- dir(path = choose.dir(), pattern = '.*edit-sites.annot.xlsx')

> fnames
[1] "1-2.edit-sites.annot.xlsx"  "10-2.edit-sites.annot.xlsx" "11-2.edit-sites.annot.xlsx" "21-2.edit-sites.annot.xlsx"
[5] "31-2.edit-sites.annot.xlsx" "4-2.edit-sites.annot.xlsx" 

ptrn <- '^([[:digit:]]{1,3}-[[:digit:]]{1,3}).*xlsx'
ptrn2 <- '(.*).edit-sites.annot.xlsx'

lapply(fnames, function(z){
  suffix <- regmatches(x = z, m = regexec(pattern = ptrn, text = z))[[1]][2] # ptrn2 also works 
  file.rename(from = z, to = paste('Sample', " ", suffix, ".xlsx", sep = ""))
})
```

After running code:

```
> dir(pattern = '.*xlsx')
[1] "Sample  1-2.xlsx"  "Sample  10-2.xlsx" "Sample  11-2.xlsx" "Sample  21-2.xlsx" "Sample  31-2.xlsx"
[6] "Sample  4-2.xlsx"
```

`ptrn` and `ptrn2` are based on the sample filenames that you supplied. Since I wasn't sure if the file names are always consistent with the pattern provided, I included a `regex` pattern to match for the leading digits separated by a dash.

I tend to batch rename files (same as the example here) and include some print statements in my code (using `cat`) to show what the original name was and what it was changed to:

```
lapply(fnames, function(z){
  suffix <- regmatches(x = z, 
                       m = regexec(pattern = ptrn, text = z))[[1]][2] # ptrn2 also works 
  new_name <- paste('Sample', " ", suffix, ".xlsx")
  cat('Original file name: ')
  cat(z)
  cat("\n")
  cat('Renamed to: ')
  cat(new_name)
  cat("\n")

  file.rename(from = z, to = new_name)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed. It seems like it was more complicated than I tought

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer suits your needs, please consider accepting or upvoting for other users who might have the same issue.

Comment: Sadly I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer :(